# SSE emitter working locally but not on server

Tags: angular, spring-boot, nginx, server, eventemitter

I am using the SSE emitter to transfer notification events for the spring boot back-end to the the angular front-end. My problem is that this works fine locally on my PC, but when deploying on a server, the call is received by the back-end and treated correctly, but the front end doesn't receive anything and keeps hanging.
I have tested that on chrome to make it simpler (also works locally but not on server)
here is my SSE emitter back-end :

```
SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);
emittersMap.put(userId, emitter);
emitter.onCompletion(() -> {
    Utils.logString("Notification API track : Received onCompletion request for user " + userId, IncidentApplication.class);
    emittersMap.remove(userId);
});
emitter.onTimeout(() ->  {
    Utils.logString("Notification API track : Received onTimeout request for user " + userId, IncidentApplication.class);
    emittersMap.remove(userId);
});
emitter.onError((e) ->  {
    Utils.logString("Notification API track : Received onError request for user " + userId, IncidentApplication.class);
    emittersMap.remove(userId);
});
try {
    emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().name("message").data("init"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    emittersMap.remove(userId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("X-Accel-Buffering", "no");
ResponseEntity<SseEmitter> response = new ResponseEntity<SseEmitter>(emitter, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
return response;
```

I have tried adding these to the nginx configuration on the server but it didn't work :

```
proxy_set_header Connection '';
proxy_http_version 1.1;
chunked_transfer_encoding off;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_cache off;
```

is there any modifications or additional configuration that I need to do on the server to make this work ?

Comment: Could you provide your frontend snippet? BTW, were there any errors inside the Chrome console during server tests? Cause the first thing I stumbled with while integrated SSE was CORS.

Comment: i know the problem is not with the front-end because even Chrome didn't work when deployed on server, so the problem is regardless of the front-end connection.
No, there were no errors on the front end side, the front end and browser (when hitting the URL directly)  are waiting for the emitter to be received